# how to find the enumerated values inside error object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was checking in our website how to know if a file already exists or not, and I found the below posted code
my question is, as seen in the following line: `err.code !== 'EEXIST'`

what kind of values also exist in `err.code`? I tried to print the entire object as follows:

```
...
...
if (err) {
    console.log('[FeatureDescriptor]: ERROR ' + err.code);
    return;
}
//output:[FeatureDescriptor]: ERROR ENOENT
```

how can I find the enumerated values inside err.code??

***code***:

```
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')

const mkdirSync = function (dirPath) {
    try {
        fs.mkdirSync(dirPath)
    } catch (err) {
        if (err.code !== 'EEXIST') throw err
    }
}
```

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#nodejs-error-codes

Comment: You mean how can you find out what other possible values `err.code` can take?

Comment: @Aron yes exactly

Comment: As @James said: https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#nodejs-error-codes

Comment: Scroll up a bit from the anchor to see "Common System Errors" including EEXIST.